# AngularJS: How to excecute a ng-init after an interval

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am loading objects into an array from a google spreadsheet. But when i want to show these objects automaticly when the page loads. The problem is that to load those objects it takes a second or 2. So my page is fully loaded before my initialisation is complete. This way it won't show the objects untill i call the controller once more. So my question is: can i call a function with ng-init after the initialisation is done?

initialisation:

```
this.partsInit = function(){
        jQuery.getJSON(this.ssl).success(function(data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                var id = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$id.$t;
                var name = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$name.$t;
                var price = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$price.$t;
                var notcompatiblewith = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$notcompatiblewithkommagescheiden.$t;
                var img = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$img.$t;
                var comp = notcompatiblewith.split(",")

                $rootScope.parts.push({"id": parseInt(id), "name": name, "price": parseInt(price), "comp": comp, "img": img, "canAdd": true, "added": false});
            };
        });
    };
```

ssl equals to: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1l4XTKaLZihj5WDRuZJE5Y7RQ7Cr7SD_-tH0ctwhizWc/od6/public/values?alt=json'

html:

```
<div class="someName" ng-init="pl.partsInit()">
<ul class="plist">
        <li ng-repeat="part in pl.parts | orderBy:'+price'" ng-hide="part.added || !part.canAdd" class="plLi">
            <div class="plistDivName">
                {{part.name}}   <!--alternatief: -->
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="{{part.img}}" class="listIMG"></img>
            </div>
            <div>
                {{part.price | currency : "&euro;"}} <!-- | currency om 2 cijfers na de komma te krijgen -->
            </div>
            <div class="plistDivButton">
                <button ng-click="pl.ap = pl.ap + 1; pl.jadd(part.id); pl.stillPossible(part.id)" ng-show="part.canAdd" class="addButton">+</button> <!-- veranderd value van pl.parts.added naar true -->
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: you can add a `ng-if="ready"` next to your `ng-init` and only set `$scope.ready` after your initialization is complete

Comment: delaying with a  timeout the call inside ng-init would be a very bad practice (what if the user has a slow connexion?). Can you update your question,  showing the way you call your spreadsheets and the way you initiate your controller?

Comment: Are you using $http service to load your data into that array? Where is that data coming from?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe i updated the question, any more code/info you need?

Comment: @BramWillems : Have you had a look at $routeProvider.when('/path',{ resolve:{...}? It can make the promise approach a bit cleaner. It helps to solve your problem i hope .

Comment: @ChrisHermut i added the code to the question

Comment: @BramWillems I don't have a solution, but a few remarks that may solve your issues. Angular has a library to query API. You should use it (`$http.get()`). If you don't Angular is not  aware that his datamodel changed, and wont bind new values.

Comment: Use $http service. Why mixing jQuery with AngularJs?

Comment: @BramWillems I know ng-init looks like the  way to initialize a controller, but it's not. Keep the initialization logic into your controller and it will be fine  : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Template Code by which you can modify as you needed.

```
// at the bottom of your controller
var init = function () {
   // ---------- Your Code ----------

};
// and fire it after definition
init();
```

Also you can take a look at [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive. Implementation will be much like:

```
// register controller in html
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl" data-ng-init="init()"></div>

// in controller
$scope.init = function () {
   // ---------- Your Code ----------
};
```

I used ng-init when I wanted to pass a value from back-end into angular app:

```
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl" data-ng-init="init('%some_backend_value%')"></div>
```